# Quantifying Over Functions In Henkin Semantics

Tags: model-theory, second-order-logic

I am trying to understand the Henkin Semantics for Second Order logic and, and I’m confused on the following point.

The Comprehension Axioms are typically defined as follows: for every second order formula $\phi(\bar{x})$ with free variables in $\bar{x}$, we have the axiom:
$$
\exists R \:\forall \bar{x} \: R(\bar{x}) \leftrightarrow \phi(\bar{x}) \tag{1}\label{3}
$$

However in some treatments of the topic (for example Section 9 of https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/) it seems that $\phi$ is allowed to have free second order variables other than $R$. Say for example $\phi$ contains some predicate symbol $P$, and consider the associated comphrehension axiom
$$
\exists R \: \forall \bar{x} \: R(\bar{x}) \leftrightarrow \phi(\bar{x}, P)
$$

in particular lets just focus on this concrete case where $R,P$ are both unary and $\phi$ is a very simple sentence:
\begin{gather}
\exists R \: \forall x \: R(x) \leftrightarrow \lnot P(x) \tag{2}\label{1} 
\end{gather}

Is it correct that in such an axiom, $P$ is being implicitly universally quantified as a second order variable? In particular is the following a valid comprehension axiom for the Henkin Models:
$$
\forall P \: \exists R \: \forall x \: R(x) \leftrightarrow \lnot P(x) \tag{3}\label{2} 
$$

I do not see any way to interpret \ref{1} other than \ref{2}, however I have sometimes seen the axioms presented in the form of \ref{1} rather than \ref{2}.

The reason I ask is that it also seems reasonable to define the Henkin semantics so that comprehension (i.e. \ref{3}) only holds for formulas $\phi(\bar{x})$ which contain no free second order variables. In this case there seems to be no reason that a Henkin model would have to satisfy a sentence like \ref{2}.

Comment: Please give specific references rather than just saying "in some treatments". The Henkin semantics (as I understand it) makes no presuppositions about axioms like comprehension in the object logic.

Comment: Thank you, I have updated with an example. From my understanding the Henkin semantics can be defined by a second order theory T, whereby a sentence is valid in all Henkin models if and only if it holds in every general model of T. The theory T is typically built by a combination of “comphrehension axioms” and “choice axioms” (as in the link I above) which are the axioms to which I’m referring (but please correct me if this is a misunderstanding).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, note that you are confusing 2 concepts, you have the semantics, and you have the deductive systems (axioms).

- Semantics is how you define the meta relation "satisfy".
- Deductive system defines what is a "legal" proof.

Your question is about the deductive system of second order logic. It is agnostic to the semantics you choose to use (Henkin/full).

In the site you linked, [they define Henkin semantics at 9.1](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-higher-order/#GeneModeHenkMode) (they call it Henkin models) while in chapter 3 they defined the standard semantics (which is also called full semantics, or full models).

---

Now for the question, I believe it should be the first case, there can be other free variables, the only restriction is that $R$ is not free